# How to save and load highscore locally

Tags: java, android, database

So I have to create a **simple** highscore system, that will save the highscore somewhere in the system memory so that it won't reset every time I open the application.

For this, I guess the correct answer is to use the "Room" database. I've watched a lot of tutorials but I still didn't understand anything.

Here is what I want to do:

```
//my ints:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int score = 0;
int highscore;
//and so on...
}

//load on app launch:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //load from database

//save new highscore
private void save_highscore () {
if (highscore > score) {
    //save to database module 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to store it locally, you can use [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

Comment: I believe this is as detailed for Room beginner as it gets: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use SharedPreferences if you don't want to use Room.

save to:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_pref_key", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", yourValue);
editor.commit();
```

load to:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_pref_key", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 int myValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", -1);
```

-1 is a default value.

Comment: This is the best way if you just want to save the high score. No need for the extra complexity that comes with handling a database engine.